# Get text from each element with certain class and then add up

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to do some calculations using javascript. I'm basically getting the text of each element with a certain class, convert that to a number and then add those numbers up.
This is what I've got so far:

```
<p class="item-size">1000</p>
<p class="item-size">2000</p>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("item-size");
    var size = ''
    for (var i=0; i<elements.length; i++) {
        size += parseInt((elements[i].innerText).replace(/[^0-9.]/g, ""));
    }
    console.log(size);
});
```

This returns `10002000` in the console. However, I need to get each of those values and then add them up instead of displaying them as one number. So the result should be 3000.
I've tried this:

```
var myTotal = 0;
for(var i = 0, len = size.length; i < len; i++) {
    myTotal += size[i][1];  
    console.log(myTotal);
}
```

However, this returns NaN. Any ideas how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a number as target variable.

```js
 $(document).ready(function(){
      var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("item-size");
      var size = 0; // <-- zero instead of an empty string
      for (var i=0; i<elements.length; i++) {
          size += parseInt((elements[i].innerText).replace(/[^0-9.]/g, ""), 10); // take base
      }
      console.log(size);
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="item-size">1000</p>
<p class="item-size">2000</p>
```

Comment: Thanks! If i need to multiply the numbers instead of add I assume I'd do           size *= parseInt((elements[i].innerText).replace(/[^0-9.]/g, ""));
however this returns 0?

Comment: then you need to start with one as neutral value for multiplication.

Comment: aaah thanks! will accept your answer in a couple of min

Answer (score 1):

`var size = 0`, when you add string with integer it will return string and calculated as string. int + str = str

---

Here's ES5 version:

```
const elements = document.getElementsByClassName("item-size");
const size = Object.keys(elements)
    .reduce((acc, curr) =>
        acc + parseInt(elements[curr].innerText.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, "")), 0)
console.log(size);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/becg3vqu/3/

Comment: that's simple problem, but frustrating

Answer (score 0):

Loop through all the children of an element and for each one increment a number by the `textcontent` of the element with a [unary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_negation).

```js
function getSumOfClass(className, root) {
  if (!(root instanceof HTMLElement)) root = document.body;
  return [].reduce.call(root.querySelectorAll("." + className),
    (result, dom) => result + (+dom.textContent || 0), 0);
}

console.log(getSumOfClass("item-size"));
```

```html
<p class="item-not-size">500</p>
<p class="item-size">1000</p>
<p class="item-size">2000</p>
```

Adding a `+` or a `-` infront of a parameter or literal will convert it to a number. If it can't be converted to a number, the result will be `NaN` so you can just add an `||` operator to return a 0 in that case (so that the non arithmetic value will be ignored).

Answer (score 0):

Using javascript vanilla

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

</head>

<body>
  <p class="item-size">1000</p>
  <p class="item-size">2000</p>
  <script>
    //getting the texts that contain numbers
    let items = document.getElementsByClassName("item-size");
    let sum = 0;
    //Now for each element in the arrays
    for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
      sum = sum + parseInt(items[i].innerText);
    }
    console.log(sum);
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since size is initially an empty string the addition wont work as you expected. Initialize var size to 0.